# My APP is NOT WORKING with img srcIMAGE SRC

Tags: android, android-layout

As soon as I add the src of the image, my apps stops running of the phone. Here is the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/er5Jp.png)

on running the app I am getting this message
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muVdN.png)

But suprisingly on removing android:src statement app is running on phone.

Comment: add `android:contentDescription` that may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are getting **OutOufMemory** error, because I guess, you are placing the imaces into **drawable** folder directly.

You should place your every density versions of images into drawable folders like below:

```
drawable-xxxhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
```

If you resize your every image and place them into these folders correctly, your device does not need to resize and scale them every single time.

Read this article carefully: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html